# finite or infinite many  quadratic fields embedding into quaternion algebras?

Tags: peano-arithmetic, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $H$ is a indefinite quaternion algebra over $\mathbb{Q}$.  Are there infinitely many quadratic fields that can be embedded into $H$?

Comment: Since a finite field has characteristic $p$, you certainly can't embed in in a $\mathbb{Q}$ algebra. Did you mean to ask something else?

Comment: I mean some quadratic field can be embeded into H, my question is how many such field ,is ther finite or infinite many?

Comment: OK, I see what you're asking. Infinitely many, as explained below...

Comment: Fixed up the language a bit.  Feel-free to undo if this was not a faithful rewording.

Comment: Inf. many: if $A$ is c.s.a. of deg. $n^2$ over field $L$ then deg-$n$ ext'n field $L'/L$ embeds in $A$ if and only if it splits $A$. For global $L$, get a finite collection of local conditions (by global & local CFT), and so satisfied for inf. many $L'$. For *any* field $L$ the $L$-isom. classes of finite \'etale $L$-subalgebras of rank $n$ in $A$ correspond to $L$-rat'l conj. classes of max'l $L$-tori in $L$-group $G$ of units of $A$. Probably any non-comm. conn'd reductive group over any finitely generated infinite field has infinitely many rational conj. class of max'l tori; is it known? 

Comment: If $T$ is max. $L$-torus in $G$ then $V := G/N_G(T)$ is "variety of max. tori"; e.g. for $L'/L$, $V(L')$ "is" set of max $L'$-tori in $G$ functorially in $L'/L$ and compatibly with left action of $G(L')$ going over to $G(L')$-conjugation on such tori. So same to ask if $G(L)\backslash V(L)$ is infinite. To prove yes, can replace $G$ with max'l adjoint ss qt. Have $G(L)\backslash V(L)$ is kernel of ${\rm{H}}^1(L,N(T)) \rightarrow {\rm{H}}^1(L,G)$ (I, 5.4, Cor. 1 to Prop. 36 in Serre's "Galois Cohomology"). Looks tractable for global $L$; answer must be "well-known" in general. Skip? George?

Comment: This is essentially proved in this paper (see Theorem 1.2):
http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2004-132-09/S0002-9939-04-07544-6/home.html



Comment: Dear Agol: Are you responding to TOM's question or to the question in my comment?  If the latter, then I don't the logical connection and am surprised that a theorem on subgroups of $\mathbf{C}$-points of a linear algebraic $\mathbf{C}$-group group could imply anything about the arithmetic topic of $G(L)$-conjugacy (but maybe I am missing some standard trick). 

Comment: By the way, G. Prasad tells me that my question about infinitude of tori can be handled by his 2003 MRL paper of his with Rapinchuk "Existence of irreducible...".  The point is that finitely generated infinite fields admit infinitely many inequivalent valuations (even with completion a local field!), and their paper produces tori having independently prescribed local behavior at finite collections of such places, more specifically being split at some places and anisotropic at others.  The crux is to make regular semisimple rational pts with prescribed local behavior.

Comment: @BCnrd: I wasn't aware of an argumen until reading the (nice) one of Prasad you just described; that sounds to me like the "right" way to argue infinitude of rational conj classes of tori for fin. generated infinite fields. Perhaps for global L there are more direct references, though? Maybe Skip knows more on this than I do? 

Comment: Dear George: For global fields I expect that can make a nice argument using the vanishing of degree-1 cohomology of simply connected groups when there's no real place (and the description when there are real places), together with results about Galois cohomology of groups of multiplicative type over global fields. But after hearing Gopal's argument that works in general (and, as you say, is clearly the "right" way), the motivation to work out the idea for the global field case fizzled away.  If Skip knows a reference where that idea is fleshed out, it will be nice to hear. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are infinitely many. Let $V$ be the subspace of $H$ where the trace is zero. Then norm gives an nondegenerate quadratic form on $V$. For any $v \in V$, the field $\mathbb{Q}(v)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-N(v)})$. Recall that the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_1})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D_2})$ are isomorphic if and only if $D_1/D_2$ is a square.

So we need to show that $V$ takes infinitely many values in $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$.  For example, if we are dealing with the standard quaternion algebra, we need to show that $p^2+q^2+r^2$ takes infinitely many values in $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$. This is easy enough that probably any method you think of will work. Here is what I came up with: Take $u$ and $v$ linearly independent members of $V$. Let $a=u^{-1} v$.

First, suppose that $-N(a)$ is a square, say $k^2$. Then, for $s$ and $t \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $N(su+tv) = N(u) N(s+t a)= N(u) (s-kt)(s+kt)$, and this expression clearly takes infinitely many values in $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$ as we vary $s$ and $t$.

If $N(a)$ is not a square, let $K=\mathbb{Q}(a)$, this is a subfield of $H$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{N(a)}]$. For $b \in K$, we have $N(ub) = N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b) N(u)$, and $ub$ is in $V$. Since there are infinitely many primes that split principally in $K$, there are infinitely primes that occur as norms $ N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(b)$, and thus we get an infinite subgroup of  $\mathbb{Q}^*/(\mathbb{Q}^*)^2$.

Answer (score 11):

To supplement David's answer: there is a standard "local-global" criterion for determining whether a quadratic field $K/\mathbb{Q}$ can be embedded in a rational quaternion algebra $B/\mathbb{Q}$.

For this recall that $B$ is said to be **ramified** at a prime number $p$ if $B_p = B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a division algebra.  Moreover, we say that $B$ ramifies "at infinity" if $B_{\infty} = B \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}$ is a division algebra.

It is known that a rational quaternion algebra $B$ is determined up to isomorphism by the set of ramified places $p \leq \infty$, that this set of places is finite and of even cardinality, and conversely for any finite set of even cardinality there is a rational quaternion algebra ramifying at these places.

Now, let $B$ be a rational quaternion algebra, $K$ a quadratic field, and $p \leq \infty$ a ramified place of $B$.  Suppose that we have an embedding $K \hookrightarrow B$.  Then tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}_p$ we get $K_p := K \otimes \mathbb{Q}_p \hookrightarrow B_p$.

Now, if $p$ is inert or ramified in $K$, then $K_p$ is a quadratic field extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and it turns out that every such quadratic extension does indeed embed in $B_p$.  However, if $p$ is split in $K$, then $K_p \cong \mathbb{Q}_p \times \mathbb{Q}_p$ has nontrivial idempotent elements, so cannot embed in $B_p$ if the latter is a division algebra.  (If $p = \infty$, then we say that $p$ is split in $K$ iff $K$ is a real quadratic field.)

In summary, this gives a necessary local criterion for the embeddability of $K$ into $B$: each ramified prime $p \leq \infty$ of $B$ is nonsplit in $K$.  By the local-global theory of quaternion algebras over $\mathbb{Q}$, it turns out that this necessary condition is also sufficient.  In particular, the quadratic fields which embed into a given quaternion algebra are precisely those which are determined by finitely many splitting conditions.

It follows easily from this that there are infinitely many quadratic fields which embed in $B$, for instance any imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ where $D$ is divisible by each finite ramified prime $p$ of $B$.  Moreover, one can see that the set of such quadratic fields has, in some natural sense, positive density (as does its complement, unless $B \cong M_2(\mathbb{Q})$ in which case we recover the result that every quadratic field embeds, as one sees much more easily by a Cayley's Theorem / regular representation style argument).

Comment: Note that this is a fleshing out of part of BCnrd's comment above, phrased in a somewhat more middlebrow way.